# how i get clicked CommandLink id in Controller in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2.2

```
<ui:repeat value="#{prodCtr.paginator.model}" var="o">                     
                <h:form> 
                    <h:commandLink  id="#{o.id}" action="ModelInfo.xhtml" actionListener="#{prodCtr.listener}">                         
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="border: #ffffff">
                            <img  src="resources/images/#{o.id}.jpg"  style="width: 100px;height: 100px"/>                            
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{o.price} YTL" style="font-size: 12px;font-family: Georgia, Serif;color: #ff3300" />  
                            <h:commandButton   value="Sifaris et" class="button"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>  
                    </h:commandLink>                                
                </h:form>

        </ui:repeat>
```

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException caught during processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=Empty id attribute is not allowed here**

How can i CommandLink id dinamically?Is there an other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't *need* to specify the `id` attribute for the child components when using the `<ui:repeat/>` tag. It automatically does this.
2. If you do want to be in control of the `id` attribute, `<ui:repeat/>` is the wrong one to use for that. The reason is that at point in time that the components are being placed in the `UIViewroot` (essentially when the page is being constructed for the first time), the `<ui:repeat/>` component is not active, i.e. it's not being processed. So the `var="o"` is not available to the runtime and so nothing is available to be used as `id`.

   To be in control of the `id`, you should be using the `<c:forEach/>` tag instead. Your code should look like this:

   ```
    <c:forEach items="#{prodCtr.paginator.model}" var="o"> 
         <h:form> 
               <h:commandLink  id="#{o.id}" action="ModelInfo.xhtml" actionListener="#{prodCtr.listener}">                         
                   <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="border: #ffffff">
                       <img  src="resources/images/#{o.id}.jpg"  style="width: 100px;height: 100px"/>                            
                       <h:outputLabel value="#{o.price} YTL" style="font-size: 12px;font-family: Georgia, Serif;color: #ff3300" />  
                       <h:commandButton   value="Sifaris et" class="button"/>
                   </h:panelGrid>  
               </h:commandLink>                                
           </h:form>

   </c:forEach>
   ```