# primefaces slider in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to create slider in ui:repeat but I encounter some problems with components ids.
More specifically, I have the following code:

```xml
<p:panel id="discounts3">
    <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.list}" var="item" varStatus="status">
        <p:panel header="Discount Schema  #{(status.index+1)}">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value"
                styleClass="grid">
                <h:outputText value="Paired solution: " />
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{item.pairedSolutionString}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{step2bBean.solutionsListAsStrings}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="Discount (%): " />
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputText id="output#{(status.index+1)}"
                        value="#{item.discount}%" />
                    <h:inputHidden id="txt#{(status.index+1)}"
                        value="#{item.discount}" />
                    <p:slider for="txt#{(status.index+1)}"
                        display="output#{(status.index+1)}" style="width:150px"
                        displayTemplate="%{value}">
                        <p:ajax event="slideEnd"
                            listener="#{step2bBean.onSlideEnd2}" />
                    </p:slider>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:panel>
```

The problem is that despite the fact that `Discount Schema  #{(status.index+1)}` is calculated correctly, the ids for example `id="output#{(status.index+1)}"` are not computed (for the specific example is set to "output").
I have tried also with dataTable with no luck.
Can you give me any hint please?
Thank you!

Comment: Try generating dynamic ids based on your data-model / unique id in list such as primaryKey.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19347968/1530938